# Combining ssh through 'term' with 'tramp' to open file in buffer

Tags: buffers, tramp, ansi-term

Often I `ssh` onto a remote machine from `ansi-term` and wish to open various files in Emacs. As I see it, there are two options:

1. `emacs -nw filename` - hiding the terminal, opening the file in the current buffer and generally creating all sorts of havoc with the key-bindings
2. `emacs filename` - opening in new window

Ideally, I'd like to use `emacs filename` to open the file in a separate buffer in the current window. I'm wondering if such a function exists, or if it might be easily written. Between `ansi-term` and `tramp`, the machinery seems to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`M-x shell` and `eshell` can possibly be made to do this entirely in elisp? They don't seem to do so by default, but it might be worth digging a bit if you're keen.

`ansi-term` is a bit of a hybrid case, but it seems that some [`PROMPT_COMMAND` trickery](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTermHints#RemoteDirectoryTracking) can be used with an external command to get a similar result.

To do this for remote shells *in general* (regardless of Emacs) -- I believe you'll need some external support for invoking emacsclient back on your local machine with the appropriate tramp path.

Here's [my old suggestion for doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5155500/324105), and that then led me to notice a variety of other solutions from other folks. Ryan Barrett lists several along with his own solution in his [emacsclient in TRAMP remote shells](http://snarfed.org/emacsclient_in_tramp_remote_shells) blog post. Harold Abnabit then elaborates on Ryan's approach in [Emacsclient and TRAMP](http://blog.habnab.it/blog/2013/06/25/emacsclient-and-tramp/).

(n.b. I have not tested any of these solutions myself)

Comment: My limited testing suggested that `M-x shell` didn't perform as desired but the first link worked beautifully, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> ... open file in a new Emacs buffer, but in the same window. The effect would be the same as using C-x C-f /ssh:host:path-to-file.

Have you tried tramp through the command line? Say you normally invoke a local file as:

```
emacs /path/to/local/file
```

then to invoke a remote file, try this:

```
emacs --eval '(find-file "/ssh:user@remote.host.com:/path/to/remote.file")'
```

The effect would be the same as using

```
C-x C-f /ssh:user@remote.host.com:/path/to/remote.file
```

inside Emacs.

> The progression would be: a) ansi-term b) ssh remote_machine c) emacs file

then why not run emacs through the ssh command like so?

```
ssh remote_machine 'emacs /path/to/file'
```

Comment: This is perhaps a little closer, but in the problem at hand I'm already on the host machine in the Emacs terminal. The progression would be: a) `ansi-term` b) `ssh remote_machine` c) `emacs file`.

Comment: @glinka, see the expanded response

Comment: Appreciate your input! This is indeed what I currently do, but I don't have superuser privileges on the remote machine and the Emacs version there is broken so it'd be far nicer to use the local Emacs to open the file.

Comment: You don't need superuser privileges to use any of the solutions given by me or the others. I don't know how or why you think so. Maybe you need to rephrase your needs more clearly, give the exact commands you use and behaviors you want/don't want. The only other solution I can think of is to use remote editing via X-Wndows remote display functions. But for that you'll have to be a lot more forthcoming with details about your setup.

Comment: Apologies, it was poorly worded. I meant only that I cannot install a clean, updated and working version of Emacs without `sudo`. I understand that none of your suggestions require elevated privileges. I think @phils may have a solution though, I need to test it out.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it was indeed a language problem as I suspected.

Answer (score 0):

You can always open a remote file in your local Emacs, it doesn't depend on ansi-term. Just do `C-x C-f /ssh:host:path-to-file`.

Comment: Right, I'd essentially like to use this functionality in the context of `ansi-term`. It seems doable.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean with this? An example, what you mean with "in the context of ansi-term"?

Comment: I'd like to issue the command `emacs file` at the `ansi-term` prompt in Emacs, and have this open `file` in a new Emacs buffer, but in the same window. The effect would be the same as using `C-x C-f /ssh:host:path-to-file`. Does that clear it up?

Comment: I understand what you intend to do, but I don't understand why you want to do. Why do you want to start an Emacs process on the other machine?